Internal $\operatorname{Hom}(1, X)=X$ in a closed monoidal category?
If $R$ is a graded-commutative ring, we know that $\operatorname{Hom}^*(R,M)\simeq M$ for each graded $R$-module $M$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a closed monoidal category (could also assume that it is symmetric), with unit object $1$ and internal $\operatorname{Hom} F$. Is it always the case that $F(1,X)\simeq X$ in the more general context of closed monoidal categories?

@S.C. After typing my answer, I saw your comment. It is in fact a duplicate! Up to the fact that one does not need symmetric which the answer at that post also states, while its title is misleading

@MPos Yeah, though you do need symmetry to have one unambiguous internal hom, instead of right and left internal homs.

By definition internal homs are subject to the tensor-hom adjunction:
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X\otimes Y, Z) \simeq \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X, \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(Y, Z))$$
In particular for $Y = \mathbb{1} \in \mathcal{C}$ it follows $\mathrm{Hom}_{C}(-, Z) \simeq \mathrm{Hom}_{C}(-,\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(\mathbb{1},Z))$ are naturally isomorphic representable functors. Yoneda lemma gives you
$$Z \simeq \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(\mathbb{1},Z).$$
